# How do I codify the unicode point U+10000 in a char16_t string literal?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11

Paragraph 2.14.5p9 in the C++11 Standard says (emphasis mine):

> A string literal that begins with u, such as u"asdf", is a char16_t
>   string literal. A char16_t string literal has type “array of n const
>   char16_t”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has
>   static storage duration and is initialized with the given characters.
>   **A single c-char may produce more than one char16_t character in the
>   form of surrogate pairs**.

How do I codify the unicode point U+10000, which is made up of the surrogate pairs D800 (high surrogate) and DC00 (low surrogate) in a char16_t string literal ?

What is meant by the `c-char` mentioned above in the quoted text?

Comment: Also you can write `char16_t s[] = {0xD800, 0xDC00, 0}` if you want to specify the code units explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple actually: `u"\U00010000"`. As stated in the text, a single *c-char* (in this case `\U00010000`) can produce more than one `char16_t`. A quick test will reveal that the type of `u"\U00010000"` is `char16_t const[3]` (2 for the surrogate pair + 1 for the null terminator).

Alternatively, you can simply put the character directly in the string, as `u""`, assuming the source file is saved with an encoding your compiler expects. This will be exactly the same thing, because one of the first steps performed on a source file is to replace any character outside the basic character set with its *universal-character-name* (i.e. `\U00010000`).

A *c-char* is "any member of the source character set except the single-quote `'`, backslash `\`, or new-line character", or an *escape-sequence* (like `\n`, or `\123`, or `\x41`), or an *universal-character-name* (like `\u1234` or `\U12345678`).

The standard document has an index of grammar productions near the end that you can use to look up these things.

Comment: Strange but this: `int main() { const char16_t* p = u"\U00010000"; }` doesn't compile in VS2010.

Comment: AFAIK VS2010 doesn't have full support for this. Works on GCC, for example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=246a7abdc0e7467e8bd59df26244f77c-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51